# How to write solution to a .sol file while using cbc in pyomo? How can I get the name of the .sol file after model is solved?

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I am using pyomo on Jupyter Notebook. I have kept `keepfiles = true` in `solve`.I am able to get the location of .sol file where it is stored. How can I get the filename of the .sol file created for the current instance?

I have used following:

```
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
SolverFactory("cbc").options['solu']="solution_file.sol"
```

But this does not work in creating the desired solution file.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `keepfiles=True` option to your call to `solve` the temporary files that are used to pass the model to the solver and read in the results will not be deleted and the path to them will be printed on the screen. So I would create and call your solver using something like:

```
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
solver = SolverFactory("cbc")
solver.solve(model, keepfiles=True)
```

Comment: This does ensure that the solution file is preserved, but does not let you control the name and location of the solution file, in case one needs to use it further after the solve.